# What is the recommended Python module for fast Fourier transforms (FFT)?

Tags: python, benchmarking, fft

Taking speed as an issue it may be better to choose another language, but what is your library/module/implementation of choice for doing a 1D fast Fourier transform (FFT) in Python?

Comment: Python packages that do FFTs will generally not be implementing them in pure Python but in an underlying compiled language, so Python's speed will not be reflected in the speed of the transform.  That is, they will be as fast as anything else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend using the [FFTW](http://www.fftw.org) library ("the fastest Fourier transform in the West").  The [FFTW download page](http://www.fftw.org/download.html) states that Python wrappers exist, but the link is broken.  A Google search turned up [Python FFTW](http://developer.berlios.de/projects/pyfftw/), which provides Python bindings to FFTW3.

Answer (score 8):

I would recommend numpy library, I not sure if it's the fastest implementation that exist but but surely it's one of best scientific module on the "market".

Answer (score 6):

FFTW would probably be the fastest implementation, if you can find a python binding that actually works.

The easiest thing to use is certainly [scipy.fft](http://www.scipy.org/SciPyPackages/Fftpack?highlight=%28fft%29), though. Plus, you get all the power of numpy/scipy to go along with it.

I've only used it for a toy project (a basic music visualization) but it was fast enough to process bog standard audio at 44khz at 60fps, as far as I can remember.